# Paging through Foursquare API results with limit/offset to build a table

Tags: php, json, api, foursquare, offset

I am trying to build a very basic web page using PHP that displays a Foursquare user's 800+ tips with their Saved and Like counts in an html table for reporting and analytics purposes.  Here is an example of what I mean on foursquare:  http://foursquare.com/redbull/list/tips . (Again, redbull is just my example..I am working with an organization that has 812 tips).

Foursquare provides an api to get to this data:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/{USER-ID}/tips?oauth_token={oauth-token}&limit=200&v=20120917
```

BUT you can only get 200 results at a time and must use an offset to get the next 200, 400 and so on:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/{USER-ID}/tips?oauth_token={oauth-token}&limit=200&offset=200&v=20120917
```

In my case I would need to call the API 5 times to get all 812 tips.  I came up with a very clunky and unscalable solution where I do call the API multiple times and just keep creating rows in my table.  Here is my ugly but working solution:  http://pastebin.com/WL6kdTPY

But obviously as tips continue to grow I would need to keep modifying my code to account for each iteration of 200 more.  In the API data I can see a mention of total tips (812) so I feel like I should be able to use that to come up with a more lean solution.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second loop should do the trick :

```
<?php 


$today = date("Ymd");
$likes = 0;
$todo = 0;

$offset = 0;
$limit = 200;
do{
    $url="https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/{user-id}/tips?oauth_token={oauth_token}&limit=".$limit."&offset=".$offset."&v={$today}";
    $source = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($source, true);
    foreach($obj['response']['list']['listItems']['items'] as $item)
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td  style = 'width: 75px;'>" .  date('m/d/y', $item['createdAt']) . "</td>" ;
        echo "<td  style = 'width: 200px;'>" . $item['venue']['name'] . "</td>" ;    
        echo "<td  style = 'width: 400px;'>" . $item['tip']['text'] . "</td>" ;
        echo "<td  style = 'width: 50px; text-align: center;'>" . $item['tip']['likes']['count'] . "</td>" ;
        echo "<td  style = 'width: 50px; text-align: center;'>" . $item['tip']['todo']['count'] . "</td>" ;
        echo "</tr>";
        $likes += $item['tip']['likes']['count'];
        $todo += $item['tip']['todo']['count'];

    }
    $offset += $limit;
} while(count($obj['response']['list']['listItems']['items']) >= $limit);


?>
```

Basicly you check if the number of returned item is lower than the limit for each request. that should mean that you reached the end

Comment: hmm.. after I added a semicolon after $offset = 0 and substituted my user id and token back into the url I am only getting the first 200 results from your code.. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: sorry wrote my condition a little fast, i needed to count $obj['response']['list']['listItems']['items'] not $item :/